# How can I convert dots into bars on plotly graph?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Below is my code for server.R

```
##########
 output$trendPlot_2 <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(mygsv, x=mygsv$Hour, y=mygsv$GSV, color=mygsv$Orders, 
                 mode = "markers"
    )
##############
```

The output graph has dots on it. How can I convert them into graph without losing my 3rd dimension (color) ?

Comment: Use a reproducable example, please

Comment: Yes, without being able to load `mygsv` it is hard to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mode = "markers"` you can use `type = "bar"`

For example:
`plot_ly(x = cut, y = n, type = "bar", color = clarity, filename="r-docs/bar-color-map")`
results in: 
[image: bar chart created with R and plotly]
[Interactive version](https://plot.ly/~RPlotBot/187.embed)

For more information on bar charts with plotly and r you can check out this tutorial page: https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/

Comment: Not working.
If I do this, my dots are replaced by bars but the colors (3rd dimension) are gone.